# Disable gphoto2's verbose error messages

Tags: c, filter, gnu

`gphoto2` often appends to its error messages a stanza of advice, which is helpful the first time but just gets in the way thereafter:

```
For debugging messages, please use the --debug option.
Debugging messages may help finding a solution to your problem.
If you intend to send any error or debug messages to the gphoto
developer mailing list <gphoto-devel@lists.sourceforge.net>, please run
gphoto2 as follows:

    env LANG=C gphoto2 --debug --debug-logfile=my-logfile.txt --port
usb:002,035 -L A/store_00010001/DCIM/

Please make sure there is sufficient quoting around the arguments.
```

Can this be suppressed without brute force like these ways?

- Wrap `gphoto2` inside a `/usr/local/bin/gphoto2`, which filters its output.
- Compile from source, and comment out that part.
- `gphoto2 --quiet`, which suppresses *too* much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend dug through the source code.  He found that
errors go to stderr, advice to stdout; so the advice (but not the errors) is suppressed by

```
gphoto2 ... > /dev/null
```

Also, `--debug` suppresses the advice, so another answer is

```
gphoto2 ... --debug --debug-logfile=/dev/null
```

For everyday use, make one of those an alias in whatever shell you use.